# How do I install Windows 7 on a Toshiba Satellite L855-S5405 Laptop?

Tags: windows

I want to install Windows 7 Pro x64 on a Toshiba Satellite L855-S5405 laptop which has Windows 8 on it because I hate Windows 8. I know I to do some things in the bios but when I have tried it before on another computer it was a nightmare and I gave up. Can you please tell me what to do.

Comment: install StartIsBack (http://startisback.com/), Aero Glass (http://glass8.eu/) and OldNewExplroer (http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-make-your-81-explorer-work-like-win78-one/) and you have a better Windows 7 based on the Windows 8 core.

Answer (score 0):

You can't downgrade from Windows 8 to a Windows Pro version. In fact, most of the time (without your system builder's permission and following [Windows' policy](http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=MJagy4bxuWr)) you can't directly downgrade. But if you have the Windows install disks for the version you are wanting to install (Windows 7 Pro x64), you can boot up from the disk and 'Upgrade' Windows by either using the upgrade installation option or using the custom installation option without formatting the hard disk. [The installation instructions can be found here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/installing-reinstalling-windows#1TC=windows-7).You should backup all of your file and programs just in case. And if you find Windows 7's upgrade doesn't support Windows 8 just use the custom installation option without formatting the hard disk witch would erase your programs, settings, and files so make sure to backup and restore them.